# How to highlight cell that does not contain specific text from any column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel file with 2 excel sheet. The sheets are called first and second.
For the first sheet, it contain 1 column, animal while the other sheet, it contains 1 columns, sentence.

name of the 1st sheet: first

> **animal**
>
> cat
>
> fly
>
> deer
>
> dog
>
> deer
>
> snail

name of the 2nd sheet: second

> **sentence**
>
> thedogpoops
>
> thedeerismyinhouse
>
> where is my cat
>
> theflyis annoying

In the first sheet, if any of the animal is not contained in the second sheet, it should be highlighted. "snail" should be highlighted in animal sheet

I used search excel formula to do this. I go to conditional formatting and use a formula to determine which cells to format. I implemented the code

=NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Sheet 1'!$A:$A,$A:$A))) 
The output is that the whole animals is highlighted

What I am trying to do is that if the animal is not found in any of the column, it will be highlighted. However it does not work. Can you please correct this problem?

Comment: I apologize as I do not want the error to be displayed but I want the animal to be highlighted instead of an error.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example this should work:

`=if(A3="","",if(count(search(A3,second!$A:$A))>0,":-)",":-("))`

**ARRAY FORMULA press SHIFT + CTRL + ENTER to enter formula**

You can place that beside the animal and pull it down.

You can use conditional formatting on the list to highlight like in my case ":-(" the sad smiley or you use better visible letters for highlighting.

If you just want to highlight the "missing" animals, then delete the happy smiley  from the formula.

`=if(A3="","",if(count(search(A3,second!$A:$A))>0,"",":-("))`

**ARRAY FORMULA press SHIFT + CTRL + ENTER to enter formula**

Comment: Generally speaking, '**array formula**' is a more common term than 'matrix formula' and we try to use the regional list separators (i.e. `,` vs `;`) that the OP has used in any sample formula they provide in the question. Yeah, it's a pain but it's how we hang.

Comment: my bad, was just chnging the function names and forgot about changing the separators. changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Select column A on the Animals worksheet and create a CFR based on this formula,

```
=isna(match("*"&$A1&"*", 'Sheet 2'!$A:$A, 0))
```

By 'wildcarding' the match to the value in the 'Animals' worksheet you are creating a 'contains within' criteria to any string in Sheet 2's column A like the non-case-sensitive SEARCH function.

Rather than produce a series of images on how to do it manualy, this is the VBA equivalent.

```
With worksheets("Animals").range("a:a")
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    with .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=isna(match(char(42)&$A1&char(42), 'Sheet 2'!$A:$A, 0))")
        .Interior.Color = vbred
    end with
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

When a cell contains an error like `#VALUE!` this is **not** text with those the phrase "VALUE"; not something you can (or should) search for in this way. It is a sort of placeholder showing where an error is.

To determine whether a formula or function results in an error use `ISERROR` or `IFERROR`.

For example, if you want to return `Not Found` if your formula produces an error, you could use:

```
=IFERROR(SEARCH($A:$A,'Sheet 2'!$A:$A),"Not Found")
```

---

I prefer `VLOOKUP` for finding matches.

For example, you could enter in cell `B2` on sheet `First`:

```
=VLOOKUP("*" &A2&"*",second!$A$2:$A$5,1,FALSE)
```

...and then fill or copy the formula down to cell `A7`.

If a matching phrase is found in `Second` then it will show that phrase, otherwise it will produce an error.

This time using `ISERROR` (as well an `IF`) as an example, you could display whether or not there was a match by instead using this formula in cell `B2` on sheet `First`:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&A2&"*",second!$A$2:$A$5,1,FALSE)),"No Match","Matched!")
```

...and then fill or copy the formula down to cell `A7`.

[image: img]

---

### More Information:

- TechOnTheNet : [**How to use the ISERROR Function**](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/iserror.php)
- ExcelJet : [**How to use the Excel IFERROR Function**](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-iferror-function)

Comment: I want to highlight the animal which is not contained in any of the column. I do not want the error to be displayed.